# Scroll to top after history.back

Tags: php, jquery, scrollto

Sorry, but my english is very bad.

How can I do to scroll to top in a php-site after use history.back?

Example: The page1.php is active. I use history.back to come back 
to page0.php. page0.php is not loading again, but i will scroll 
to top with jquery.

How can I do that?

Bye, David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below script in that page, in which you want to go to top of page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
           scrollTop: 0
        }, 600);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery code to do scroll top

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $(window).scrollTop();
   //or
   $(document).scrollTop();
 });
```

Comment: This code don´t work. I have add this code bevore </body> and jquery is includet. Is it because the site after history.back is not loading again?

Comment: how you are doing history.back, through javascript??

Answer (score -1):

I am not good in this, but still check below process if that works,

check onbeforeunload event if that event occurs set the cookie, and on page check if the cookie is set then fire scroll to top event.

After that once scroll to top event occurs change the cookie value again.

Not at all sure this will work and it is a right solution, but just tried to think how it can be implemented.